# Is my iPhone 4 touchscreen malfunctioning?

Tags: iphone, touchscreen

My iPhone4 is weird. The bottom touchscreen can be slid (to unlock) but it's really hard to tap the app in the bottom area. It seem the bottom screen is not sensitive but I can slide to unlock. What's wrong with my iPhone?

Comment: Is this a new problem or has it been that way since the day you bought it? Also, did you jailbreak your phone?

Comment: @Matthew this is new problem. And I didn't jailbreak it.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Anything we can do to help you mark an answer as solving this so others can know / learn from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost certain that you have a hardware problem, something wrong with the actual touchscreen. Since the iPhone 4 is less than a year old it's still under warranty, Apple will fix it for free.

If you haven't done so already you can try a complete restore of your iPhone, erasing everything and returning it to it's brand new state (after backing it up). Odds are not good that this will fix it, but it's worth a shot, especially if having Apple repair it is a hassle.

Apple explains how to back it up and restore it here:

[**iTunes: Backing up, updating, and restoring your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch software**](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414)

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of utilities that you can use to test responsiveness of your iPhone.

Try using a webapp called [Sparky](http://spark.attrakt.se/) in order to test and see if there are in fact dead spots, alignment issues, or any other problem with your iPhone's touch screen.

Comment: Actually, it appears this webapp may no longer work. Perhaps due to the Nitro(?) JS changes made in iOS 4.3. Crap :(. My idea for testing this stands, my suggested means of doing so, does not.