# Any iPhone apps to test the touchscreen?

Tags: iphone, applications, screen, touchscreen

I've been playing an iPhone game for about a week and today the phone didn't detect some of my swipes.  It still detected most of my swipes, but on a few occasions I swiped and nothing happened.  I did drop my phone on a carpeted floor yesterday so I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Are there any apps that let you test the iPhone touchscreen?  I would think someone has developed an app that lets you touch/swipe anywhere on the screen and it gives you visual feedback that it detected your touch/swipe.  I searched in the App Store and didn't see anything.

I found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14961/23381) that said there are a few utilities that let you test the responsiveness of your iPhone, but it didn't mention the names of those utilities.  It also mentioned a web site named Sparky, but I went there on my iPhone and couldn't do anything there.

I have an iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Sparky**](http://spark.attrakt.se/) works for testing multitouch, so you can try different areas of the screen by holding one finger in a place you know works and move the other elsewhere. If the line breaks, then the second finger is in a location that doesn't work. You can test it full screen (without the Safari UI but the status bar is still present) by adding it to the home screen.

Comment: Thanks, I saw Sparky mentioned in another answer but didn't realize you had to use 2 fingers.

Comment: The code for Sparky is on GitHub, if anyone wants to experiment with it. https://github.com/lbrtw/sparky

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old post but if somebody is still looking for a solution to their touchscreen problems, there is an application on app store which helps you test the touch screen of your iPhone and iPad. its a brilliant app.
here's the link:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touchscreen-test/id1126113478?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

You can test most of the functions of iphone including the display by Phone diagnostics app.
Link to download: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phone-diagnostics/id1171677218?ls=1&mt=8 or you can search Phone diagnostics or Hitek Nova.

Answer (score 0):

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touchscreen-test/id1126113478?mt=8
--> It works.
For Google Play App, I found Phone Doctor Pro which is similar to this one:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hitek.phonedoctorpro.android